# Issues Converting String to javax.json.JsonString

Tags: java, json, jakarta-ee

I have a class that looks something like this

```
    private byte[] profilePicture;
    private ProfileType profileType;
    private String profileHandle;
    private String personalEmail;
    private Address address;
```

To convert this to Json using javax.json is like this:

```
    JsonObject payloadObject = Json.createObjectBuilder()
    .add("profilePicture", profilePictureEncoded)
    .add("profileType", profileType.ordinal())
    .add("profileHandle", profileHandle)
    .add("personalEmail", personalEmail)
    .add("webAppEmail", webappEmail)
    .add("address", address.produceJsonPayload())
    .build();
```

All good!! except sometimes there is no profile picture so I wanted to build this incrementally ie

```
    JsonObject payloadObject = Json.createObjectBuilder().build();
    if(profilePicture != null)
    {
        final String profilePictureEncoded = ..... //encode the image
        payloadObject.put("profilePicture",profilePictureEncoded);
    }
```

problem is you cant because I can't cast profilePictureEncoded to a JsonString

Has anyone got something like this working?  Or do I need to use another Json Library?

Damien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just get a reference to the `JsonObjectBuilder`.

```
JsonObjectBuilder payloadObjectBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
```

wait until you have everything while constructing

```
if(profilePicture != null)
{
    final String profilePictureEncoded = ..... //encode the image
    payloadObject.add("profilePicture",profilePictureEncoded);
}
```

and then `build()`

```
JsonObject payloadObject = payloadObjectBuilder.build();
```